# WSO2 API Manager Portable Installation

Tags: java, github, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an instance of a WSO2 API Manager 1.9.0 that works fine on my machine. I need to be able to transfer this server instance to other machines. I've pushed my code to github but when I clone it the server will not host. The log shows that the server is up at myip:port but the port is 8243 as opposed to 9443. My original instance works but the cloned instance does not.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It's apparent that when first running the server there are configurations that are set to paths on my machine. Is there a way to re run that process when starting the server?

Here's the repo 
https://github.com/Brian-Kaplan/WSO2-API-Manager

Answer (score 0):

API Manager uses both 9443 and 8243 ports. 9443 is used for Management UI, where as 8243 is used to invoke APIs.

You don't have to set any paths in configurations in API Manager, all are relative path to base directory.

Comment: Would you mind trying to clone my repo and run the server. You'll see that it hosts the management console at 8243 and is not accessible in a web browser